# Facing issue while editing record

Tags: permissions, user-record, userrecordaccess, record-access-level

i am trying to edit the record in one of the custom object, but i am getting error Insufficient Privileges.
Profile having access to read,edit,create,view all .Please suggest what is the problems is having read access.Sharing setting is Controlled by parent and opportunity is the parent which having the access read,edit,view all

Comment: Are there any sharing rule criterias specified for your custom object? i.e where Account.Name starts with 'xyz'

Comment: no.There is no Any sharing rule

Comment: Have you defined any Role Hierarchy in your org?

Comment: Yes There is roles assigned to those profiles

Comment: Then make sure User using which you want edit record is above the hierarchy of the user who has created that record. User at higher hierarchy can edit record of its subordinates while subordinates cannot edit records created by users at higher hierarchy.